# Newline in a <pre> element in internet explorer 7

Tags: html, asp.net-mvc-3, newline, internet-explorer-7, pre

I have the following code in my ASP.NET MVC 3 project:

```
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.validate.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
...    
<pre>@Html.ValidationSummary()</pre>
```

The validationsummary shows the errormessages that are specified in my model. And the model gets the errormessages out of a resource file..
In 1 of the errormessages I use newlines (shift + enter).
**These newlines are shown correctly in firefox and chrome, but not in internet explorer 7.**

Can I fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's possible that the ValidationSummary() uses unix newlines (\n) and IE only likes the Windows newlines (\r\n). See if you can replace \n with \r\n in before displaying it.

Comment: Ah! I forgot about this... you have to use a <br/> in the PRE tag for IE. I know... it's ridiculous but I've had the same problem. Try replacing "\n" with "<br/>\n"

Comment: Nope, I'm sorry. This just writes a <br /> in the validation errormessage. It seems that ie7 just can't do it. It even works in ie8...

Comment: Maybe the BR elements are being html encoded? View source and make sure they're coming through as <br/> and not &lt;br/&gt; I know that in a PHP application I have which shows log messages in a PRE tag, I have to replace newlines with BR for IE7. If not, then I'm all out of ideas. :)

Comment: I put word-wrap: break-word; in pre tag. It's better, but doesnt realy solve the problem. But thanks for your comments!